# duplicate requests in an angular component

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a component and a service that gets the component's related data from the server. I call this service inside the `.ts` file of the component that's, subscribe to the function that uses it to fetch the data. Then I use this component a few times in a template of another component. Apparently it breeds that many http GET requests (in my case these are GET requests) all of which are totally identical. I would like to avoid this by any means possible. I know perhaps one of possible solutions would be to call the service in the `ts` file of the parent component and then just inject the data into the child. But are there any other ways of doing it? Because it seems rational to call that service where it is now.

Comment: Another option would be to call the service, set the data in a shared service and check whether data is present in your shared service before actually making the call.

Comment: @Stanislasdrg Thank you, I will keep that in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you subscribe to an observable from the http service a http request is fired, once the request has been completed the observable completes. If another subscription is made then another request will fire again.

You need to cache the result of the request if you don't want another request to hit the server again.

I have written a library called ngx-rxcache and this is one of it's main purposes.

https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb

Install the library with "npm install ngx-rxcache"

Then you can create a reference data service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { RxCacheService } from 'ngx-rxcache';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RefDataService {
  private titlesCache = this.cache.get<any[]>({
    id: '[RefData] titles',
    construct: () => this.http.get<any[]>('titles'),
    autoload: true
  });

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private cache: RxCacheService
  ) { }

  get titles$(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.titlesCache.value$;
  }
}
```

This will create a service that has a titles$ observable on it, the first time it is subscribed to it will fire a http request and each time thereafter it will get it from the cache.

The constructor function should return an observable of the type of the cache, in this instance a call to the titles http get end point. The autoload property tells the cache to call the constructor function the first time the value is accessed.

Comment: Seems like a grand option. Thank you, I will try it. May I ask you some questions regarding its implementation in case I have them?

Comment: Sure. Have a read of the medium series I wrote on the library. And have a look at the demo on stackblitz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pytks5